# como cambiar el color de la fuente dentro de los comentarios de error de mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

como cambiar el color de la fuente dentro de los comentarios de error de mysql workbench??

[image: Comentarios en blanco]

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres cambiar los colores predeterminados de MySQLWorkbench tienes que editar el archivo `code_editor.xml`

En este archivo se encuentran todos los estilos de colores de los comentarios, erorres, funciones, keywords etc...

Si has hecho la instalación en Windows en la ubicación predeterminada puedes encontrar el archivo en :

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\data` --> `code_editor.xml`

En Linux se encontrara en el `path` de instalación que tienes establecido dentro de `resources/data`  --> `code_editor.xml`

***EJEMPLO DE MODIFICACIÓN***
Por si acaso te dejo un ejemplo...

En la `linea 52 y 53` encontrarás el siguiente codigo :

> ```
> <style id="1" fore-color-light="#0987cb" fore-color-dark="#0a99e5" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
> <style id="2" fore-color-light="#0987cb" fore-color-dark="#0a99e5" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
> ```

Style con id 1 se refiere a los comentarios que utilizamos como `/**COMENTARIO*/`
Style con id 2 se refiere a los comentarios que utilizamos como `-- Comentario`

Por defecto se ven de esta forma :

[image: Default]

Ahora cambiamos los colores de forma que los comentarios en bloque `/**COMENTARIO*/` tengan el codigo `#eb4034 (rojo)` y los comentarios en linea `-- COMNETARIO` el codigo `#ffff00 (amarillo)`

Para eso modificamos el archivo asignando los codigos de colores de esta forma :

> ```
> <style id="1" fore-color-light="#eb4034" fore-color-dark="#0a99e5" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENT -->
> <style id="2" fore-color-light="#ffff00" fore-color-dark="#0a99e5" /> <!-- SCE_MYSQL_COMMENTLINE -->
> ```

Guardas los cambios, y abres MySQLWorkbench. Ahora los comentarios se ven de esta forma :

[image: NoDefault]

Tienes que hacer lo mismo con tu codigo de error.

Comment: Cualquier información que necesites escribe un comentario!